# ng new hangs on Angular 13

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I have just installed angular 13 on a freshly formatted machine.

When I run the ng new command the installation hangs forever and the cmd is frozen. See below:

[image]

I have never seen this before and cannot find any solution for this. Have any of you experienced this or have suggestions on what could cause this?

**Angular version**:

[image]

**npm version**: 8.3.0

**node version**: 16.13.1

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm it seems to me this shouldn't happen Maybe it is a bug need to be reported?

Comment: maybe try debugging like this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#debugging
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/ng new test

Comment: Try it with `ng new test --verbose` and post the output. Seems to be a problem with `npm install`

Comment: I downgraded to node 14.16.1 and now it works. I had multiple pc's and build machines not working with 16.13.1 - they had the same behaviour. Dont know if there might be a bug as suggested by @ManosKounelakis. I will continue to the investigations as downgrading does not seem like a solid solution.